Optimize MongoDB aggregation
We have the following collections:

batches

_id: ObjectId

start: Date



chunks

_id: ObjectId

batchId: ObjectId

state: String (values: "PENDING" or "EXECUTED")




We need to build an aggregation to get the 10 most recently started batches with the total and pending chunk quantities corresponding to each batch.
This will be executed periodically and both collections will have a large number of documents, so we need to find the best approach.
For example, for the next sample collections:
batches:
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "661952f9b98ac85af1d6bb87"
    },
    "start": {
      "$date": "2019-07-12T04:37:59.501Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "66195333b98ac85af1dc880d"
    },
    "start": {
      "$date": "2022-03-04T22:25:37.334Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "66195306b98ac85af1d7f40f"
    },
    "start": {
      "$date": "2013-08-13T02:33:05.358Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
  }
]

and chunks:
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "661952f9b98ac85af1d6bb89"
    },
    "batchId": {
      "$oid": "661952f9b98ac85af1d6bb87"
    },
    "status": "EXECUTED",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "661952f9b98ac85af1d6bb99"
    },
    "batchId": {
      "$oid": "661952f9b98ac85af1d6bb87"
    },
    "status": "PENDING",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "661952f9b98ac85af1d6bbaf"
    },
    "batchId": {
      "$oid": "66195333b98ac85af1dc880d"
    },
    "status": "EXECUTED",
    "__v": 0
  }
]

we expect a result like this:
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "66195333b98ac85af1dc880d"
    },
    "start": {
      "$date": "2022-03-04T22:25:37.334Z"
    },
    "total": 1,
    "pending": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "661952f9b98ac85af1d6bb87"
    },
    "start": {
      "$date": "2019-07-12T04:37:59.501Z"
    },
    "total": 2,
    "pending": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "66195306b98ac85af1d7f40f"
    },
    "start": {
      "$date": "2013-08-13T02:33:05.358Z"
    },
    "total": 0,
    "pending": 0
  }
]

So far we have created 2 indexes besides the default unique index on _id field:

descending order index on start field in batches collection

ascending order index on batchId field in chunks collection


And tried with the following pipeline:
[
  {
    $sort: { start: -1 },
  },
  {
    $limit: 10,
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "chunks",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "batchId",
      as: "chunks",
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      start: "$start",
      total: { $size: "$chunks" },
      pending: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$chunks",
            as: "chunk",
            cond: {
              $eq: ["$$chunk.status", "PENDING"],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
]

Which has the next explanation plan:

Is this the best approach? Can the aggregation pipeline be written differently in order to improve performance?

Please provide some sample documents.

@WernfriedDomscheit I edited the question to add sample documents.

Have you considered adding total and pending/completed fields to each batch document?  It should be a fairly fast update to increment total when a chunk is added, and increment completed when a chunk is changed from pending to executed.  Then the status query doesn't need a lookup at all, and pending is simply total - completed.

@HernandoScheidl I am terribly sorry for missing the index definition in your question first. Firstly, this is a playground that I created to try to simulate your current query. I tried to push your later $filter and $size logic into the $lookup subpipeline to minimize the intermediate result set like this. Unfortunately, I cannot create enough test data. Do you mind have a try on your end to see if the newer version helps?
